# Is the Millennium Falcon hyperdrive from The LEGO Movie based on a previous Star Wars design?

Tags: star-wars, lego, the-lego-movie, lego-cinematic-universe

In *The LEGO Movie*, Batman steals the hyperdrive (which the heroes need) from the Millennium Falcon.

Here is a still of how the hyperdrive appears.

[image: Batman with the Hyperdrive]

Is the design for the hyperdrive, made out of LEGO blocks, based on an existing *Star Wars* design, or was it created specifically for the film?

Comment: That design of hyperdrive (or something very similar) is found in the Complete Cross-Sections book from 2007 as well as the Star Wars Blue Prints: Ultimate Collection from 2008; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SSP05_hyperdrive